# git log including only 1 feature branch

Tags: git

We have a main branch called "release", and for each features we have different feature branches which in the end will merge into "release".

I'd like to show the "git log" result only listing the commits in the main "release" branch and one feature branch that I'm interested, omitting commits of other feature branches, how could I do that?

To make it more difficult, after a feature branch is merged into the "release" branch, the branch will be (manually) deleted.

For example, consider the following commit history:

```
1---2---4------+7--8------+11----+13---->   # release branch
     \   \    /     \    /      /
      \   5--6       9--10     /       # feature-bar1 and feature-bar2 branches
       \                      /
        3-------------------12         # feature-foo

--> time

# 1 - 13 are commits
# 1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 11, 13 are the main branch "release"
# + shows a merge
# 4, 5, 6, 7 is a feature branch 'bar1' merged into "release"
# 8, 9, 10, 11 is another feature branch 'bar2' merged into "release"
# 2, 3, 12, 13 is the feature branch "foo" merged into "release"
```

I can show the whole history as

```
git log 13..1 --oneline --graph
```

Now I want to generate the changelog for `release` and `foo` branches, excluding all other branches such as `bar1` or `bar2`. This means I'd like to see

```
1---2---4-------7--8-------11----+13---->   # release branch
     \                          /
      3-----------------------12            # feature-foo
```

But there is a problem: in all feature branches, such as `bar1`, `bar2` or `foo`, are deleted after the merge. Can I still achieve this?

Comment: git deletes nothing unless it is garbage collected.

Comment: I think, you should re-formulate your question then. It is not clear what you are trying to do. As you explained, you do not need those branches in any case. Also, gc should not delete your 'bar' branches in any case, even if you manually removed references to them.

Comment: @Serge "foo", "bar1" and "bar2" are manually deleted by programmers according to the company practice, then garbage collected by git. questions updated.

Comment: @Serge: Branches aren't subject to garbage collection; they're just deleted immediately on request, perhaps subjecting their commits (and trees and blobs) to eventual garbage collection.

Comment: I think, a good way to achieve something like that would be to use two commands ```git log --first-parent``` and list the history of 13 and 12 separately. This does not show everything in one history, of course, but it is close to showing what you want.